# Получить id публичного канала телеграм

Tags: php, telegram

Имея ссылку на канал(не чат), надо получить его id'шник для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Знаю такие способы:

1. Добавить своего бота в канал (нужно быть администратором с правом добавления администраторов, т.к. бот в канал можно добавить только с правами админами). В этом случае боту придет событие, что его добавили в канал, в структурах будут видны id канала, название и т.п.
2. Есть различные боты по определению id канала, например точно работает @username_to_id_bot
   Нужно форварднуть любое  сообщение из канала такому боту и он покажет id.
   п.2 давно не пользую, т.к. хватает п.1. без проблем.
3. Поставить Plus messenger - показывает id каналов и чатов.
   Не доверяю сторонним клиентам.